# @Inject(FIREBASE) firebase:any NO Provider for token Firebase

Tags: angular, firebase

Developing angular2seedadvanced app with Firebase as backend produce an error

> no token for Firebase while using @Inject(FIREBASE) firebase:any inside the constructor.

`service.ts`

```
import { FIREBASE } from '../../myapp/index';
@Injectable()
export class LoginService {
    constructor(@Inject(FIREBASE) firebase:any) {}
}
```

Comment: Wow never seen a constructor like that before  did you intent to  import  it like constructor(private firebase: FIREBASE) {}

Comment: i want to integrate my web app with firebase. am following the link https://github.com/NathanWalker/angular-seed-advanced/wiki/How-to-integrate-Firebase-across-all-platforms-(web-nativescript-desktop)

Comment: Check this out https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/414#issuecomment-241588890

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to integrate Firebase with Angular is AngularFire (https://github.com/angular/angularfire), the official package for this.

It gives you access to the core SDK is you need the control.

You can also import firebase directly from the Firebase SDK like this:

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/firestore';
import 'firebase/storage';
import 'firebase/auth';
```

Note that you must configure the SDK before doing this.